# Error when using custom function on NHibernate mapping-by-code's SqlInsert

Tags: postgresql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I have an NHibernate mapping-by-code that works if using standard INSERT on standard SqlInsert

```
class ProductTranslationMapping : ClassMapping<ProductTranslation>
{
    public ProductTranslationMapping ()
    {
        .
        .
        SqlInsert ("insert into product_translation(product_id, language_code, product_name, product_description) values(?,?,?,?)");

        .
        .       
    }
}
```

However, I want to use Postgresql stored procedure, so both insert and update can use the same routine

```
class ProductTranslationMapping : ClassMapping<ProductTranslation>
{
    public ProductTranslationMapping ()
    {

        .       
        .
        SqlInsert ("select merge_product_translation(?,?,?,?)");
        SqlUpdate ("select merge_product_translation(?,?,?,?)");
        .
        .       
    }
}
```

However when I use Postgresql function, it has an error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
NHibernate.StaleStateException: Unexpected row count: -1; expected: 1
  at NHibernate.AdoNet.Expectations+BasicExpectation.VerifyOutcomeNonBatched (Int32 rowCount, IDbCommand statement) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NHibernate.AdoNet.NonBatchingBatcher.AddToBatch (IExpectation expectation) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert (System.Object id, System.Object[] fields, System.Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlCommandInfo sql, System.Object obj, ISessionImplementor session) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: NHibernate.StaleStateException: Unexpected row count: -1; expected: 1
  at NHibernate.AdoNet.Expectations+BasicExpectation.VerifyOutcomeNonBatched (Int32 rowCount, IDbCommand statement) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NHibernate.AdoNet.NonBatchingBatcher.AddToBatch (IExpectation expectation) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert (System.Object id, System.Object[] fields, System.Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlCommandInfo sql, System.Object obj, ISessionImplementor session) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

If it would help, here's my Postgresql stored procedure:

```
create or replace function merge_product_translation(p_product_id int, p_language_code text, p_product_name text, p_product_description text) returns int
as
$$
begin
    if not exists(select * from product_translation where product_id = p_product_id and language_code = p_language_code) then       
        insert into product_translation(product_id, language_code, product_name, product_description)
        values(p_product_id, p_language_code, p_product_name, p_product_description);
    else        
        update product_translation set
            product_name = p_product_name,
            product_description = p_product_description
        where product_id = p_product_id and language_code = p_language_code;    
    end if;

    return 1;

end;
$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

I also tried the following, but still out of luck, all of them has error:

```
SqlInsert ("perform merge_product_translation(?,?,?,?)");
SqlInsert ("call merge_product_translation(?,?,?,?)");  
SqlInsert ("{call merge_product_translation(?,?,?,?)}");
```

What should I use so I can avoid the error `unexpected row count of -1`?  It's also hard to google it, as google eliminates the -1

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate needs to check the results of its internally generated SQL commands. The same is required/applied on your *custom* implementation (stored procedures), because it is treated the same.

But there is nice solution. Read more here [17.3. Custom SQL for create, update and delete](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-cud).

The Extract:

> The stored procedures are by default required to affect the same
>   number of rows as NHibernate-generated SQL would. NHibernate uses
>   IDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery to retrieve the number of rows affected.
>   This check can be disabled by using check="none" attribute in
>   sql-insert element.

**The Solution**: ... adjust your mapping like this:

```
<sql-insert check="none" >..</sql-insert>
<sql-update check="none" >..</sql-update>
```